# Copying files based on File name in for loop in Python

Tags: python

I have a directory with multiple xlsx files.

```
1-9999.xlsx
10000-19999.xlsx
.
.
.
350000_359999.xlsx
360000_363946.xlsx
```

I'm trying to copy specific file based on some conditions. I tried the following code:

```
import os
import shutil
import glob
import re

path = "G:/Test/destina/"
new_path = "D:/dir/"

files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsx"))
files

targ = [35, 36]
targs = [f"{i}*.xlsx" for i in targ ]

for file in files:
    for targ in targs:
        if re.search(targ ,file):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, file), new_path)
```

But it doesn't work.Would someone be able to help with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the criteria?  Its hard to figure out from the code. You have `targs = [f"{i}*.xlsx" for i in array]` but `array` is not defined. Sometimes the file names have numbers separated by dash, other times by underline. Is there some standard format for these names?

Comment: Just do `glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "35*.xlsx"))`, or substitute the number.

Comment: @tdelaney, sorry about make wrong string.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, but if I have many target , I need to do it manytimes. for example, targ = [35, 36, 37, 44, 63, 69]

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Pathlib,it comes with glob method, rglob is recursive

```py
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

path = "G:/Test/destina/"
new_path = "D:/dir/"

targ = [35, 36]
targs = f'[{",".join(str(i) for i in targ)}]*.xlsx'
files = Path(path).rglob(targs)
for file in files:
    shutil.copy(file, new_path)
```

Comment: you are real 9-1-1, can help everyone!!