# Copying specific files based on multiple strings with file name in Python

Tags: python, copy

I want to copy specific files based on string what I assign to another directory.
My question similar to [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76169378/copying-files-based-on-file-name-in-for-loop-in-python)
But in my loc folder have many file like:
File name is different.

```
20220101(100000-19999).xlsx
20220101(200000-29999).xlsx
20220101(300000-39999).xlsx
20220101(400000-49999).xlsx
20220101(500000-69999).xlsx
20220101(600000-69999).xlsx
20220101(700000-79999).xlsx
20220101(800000-89999).xlsx
20220101(900000-99999).xlsx
20220101(1000000-109999).xlsx
20220101(1100000-119999).xlsx
```

So far I'm not able to copy files successfully with the below code also:

```
import shutil
import os
import glob

loc= 'C:/path/to/files/folder'
des = 'G:/path/to/files/new_folder'

pattern= ["100000", "500000"]
patterns= [f"20220101({i}*" for i in pattern]


files = Path(loc).rglob(patterns)

for file in files:
    print(file)
    shutil.copy(file, des )
```

I want get like below in my des folder when I assign pattern is "100000" and "500000".

```
20220101(100000-19999).xlsx
20220101(500000-69999).xlsx
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 10
      5 patterns= [f"20220101({i}*" for i in pattern]
      8 files = Path(loc).rglob(patterns)
---> 10 for file in files:
     11     print(file)
     12     shutil.copy(file, des)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py:1043, in Path.rglob(self, pattern)
   1038 """Recursively yield all existing files (of any kind, including
   1039 directories) matching the given relative pattern, anywhere in
   1040 this subtree.
   1041 """
   1042 sys.audit("pathlib.Path.rglob", self, pattern)
-> 1043 drv, root, pattern_parts = self._flavour.parse_parts((pattern,))
   1044 if drv or root:
   1045     raise NotImplementedError("Non-relative patterns are unsupported")

File ~\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py:66, in _Flavour.parse_parts(self, parts)
     64     continue
     65 if altsep:
---> 66     part = part.replace(altsep, sep)
     67 drv, root, rel = self.splitroot(part)
     68 if sep in rel:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: Please include the command line results of your code "not working".

Comment: Does `print` show the files you expect?

Comment: @user19077881, I got  ```<generator object Path.rglob at 0x0000017F011F0BA0>``` when print(files)

Comment: Does your `print(file)` give the correct file names within the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it can work in this way.

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

loc = 'C:/path/to/files/folder'
des = 'G:/path/to/files/new_folder'

pattern = ["100000", "500000"]
patterns = [f"20220101({i}*" for i in pattern]

files = []
for pat in patterns:
    files = files + sorted(Path(loc).rglob(pat))

for file in files:
    print(file)
    shutil.copy(file, des)
```

Cause rglob takes str as arg, but which you give was a list.

Comment: Thanks for this it works. I even used ```if``` in my code but still fail.Thank you for providing answer and tips.